# Format restrictions for cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I want a cell to only have a specified format, e.g. "01-02-03", meaning "double digit dash double digit dash double digit".

I a user tries to enter something into the cell, an error should occurr telling him if the entered value is wrong.

Is this possible without creating a macro or complex VBA-scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a validation rule that uses the following conditions:

- There has to be **2 dashes**, in the exact same positions as shown.
- With the exception of the dashes, the value contains **only numbers**.

**Setup:**

**Step1:** Select your cell and create a validation rule for it.

**Step2:** Choose **Custom** and enter the formula below (replace **A1** with the cell you're referring to in your question).

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MID(A1,1,2)+0), ISNUMBER(MID(A1,4,2)+0), ISNUMBER(MID(A1,7,2)+0), MID(A1,3,1)="-", MID(A1,6,1)="-")
```

Using this validation formula, the following sample entries will show the error "The value you entered is not valid" after the user de-selects the cell or presses **Enter** after typing the value.

```
ad-24-24
56-a6-34
456-234
123456
67-7890
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom format for a 6 digit number: `00-00-00`, and then use `Data Validation` to limit text length to 6. It will still allow non-numeric characters unfortunately.

Alternatively you use use `Whole Number` `Data Validation` between `100000` and `999999`, but obviously this wouldn't allow the number to begin with a `0`.

Comment: Sorry James looks like we we're putting in the same answer at once. I deleted mine.

Comment: @Blomkvist No probs, great minds think alike!