# Excel 2007 - cell format locking

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet that 4 users can update.  In several columns, they should only be inputting dates, but some input text.  I would like to lock the format so that if text is entered, either it is not accepted or an error appears.

Is there a way to do this without macros?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/279442/format-restrictions-for-cell-in-excel

Comment: It's close, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using validation you can enter a custom `Validation Criteria` using a formula to prevent text input. In my example the dates are entered in cells A3 through A51. Adjust this to be the cells your dates are entered into.

[image]

On the `Input Message` tab remove the check from the box. On the `Error Alert` tab you can adjust the message as you see fit.

[image]

Click `OK` to save it. When text is entered into the cell you will get an error message.

[image]